Hoeffding's inequality for variance
One of the consequences of the Hoeffding's inequality states that for all equally distributed independent random variables $X_i, \; i=1,...,n$, such that $X_i \in [a, b]$ almost surely, and with $E(X_1) = \mu$, the sample mean of the variables is close to the mean of these variables, i.e.
$$
P(|\overline{X} - \mu| \geq t) \leq 2\exp\left(-\frac{2t^2n}{(b-a)^2}\right)
$$
As a result, $P(|\overline{X} - \mu| \geq (b-a)\sqrt{2\frac{\ln T}{n}}) \leq 2T^{-4}$.
This is really powerful, but I stumbled across a problem: I need the analogue of the Hoeffding's inequality for variance, i.e. I am interested in the good upper bound of the $P(|S^2 - \sigma^2| \geq t)$, where $S^2 = \frac{n}{n-1}\left(\overline{X^2} - \overline{X}^2\right)$ is the sample variance and $\sigma^2 = Var(X_1^2)$.
Does the analogue of the Hoeffding's inequality for variance exist?

Everything follows easily from Hoeffding inequality. Let us prove it.
$$
P(|\sum_i X_i - n \mu| \geq t) \leq 2\exp(...) \quad (*)
$$
Put $Y_i = X_i^2$. Then $E Y_i = \sigma^2 +\mu^2$ and
$$
P(|\sum_i X_i^2 - n (\sigma^2 +\mu^2) | \geq t) = P(|\sum_i Y_i - n EY_1| \geq t) \leq 2\exp(...) 
$$ by Hoeffding inequality for $Y_i$. We put  $u = \frac{t}n$ and get
$$
P(|\bar{X^2} - (\sigma^2 +\mu^2) | \geq u) \leq 2\exp(...) \quad (**)
$$
Further, it follows from $(*)$ that $$
P(|\sum_i X_i - n \mu| < t) \ge 1 - 2\exp(...) \quad (***)
$$
Hence  $\sum_i X_i \in [n \mu - t, n \mu + t]$ with big probability. We will suppose that $\mu > 0$ - otherwise everything in similar. But
$$\sum_i X_i \in [n \mu - t, n \mu + t]  \Rightarrow (\sum_i X_i)^2 \in [(n \mu - t)^2, (n \mu + t)^2]  \Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow  (\sum_i X_i)^2-(n\mu)^2\in [t^2 - 2n\mu t, t^2 + 2n\mu t] \Rightarrow   (\sum_i X_i)^2-(n\mu)^2\in [-t^2 - 2n\mu t, t^2 + 2n\mu t]  $$
In other words
$$|\sum_i X_i - \mu t| < t \Rightarrow |(\sum_i X_i)^2-(n\mu)^2 | \le t^2 + 2\mu t.$$
Takint $(***)$ into account we get
$$ P(|(\sum_i X_i)^2-(n\mu)^2 | \le t^2 + 2\mu t) \ge 1 - 2exp(...).$$
Put $\tilde{t} = t^2 + 2\mu t$. We have
$$ P(|(\sum_i X_i)^2-(n\mu)^2 | \le \tilde{t}) \ge 1 - 2exp(...)$$
and
$$ P(|(\sum_i X_i)^2-(n\mu)^2 | > \tilde{t}) \le  2exp(...) $$
If we put $v = \frac{\tilde{t}}{n^2}$, we get
$$ P(|(\bar{X})^2-\mu^2 | > v) \le  2exp(...) \quad (****) $$
Further, if $|a - b| > t$ then $|a| > \frac{t}2$ or  $|b| > \frac{t}2$.
Put $$a =\bar{X^2} -  (\sigma^2 +\mu^2), \quad b = (\bar{X})^2-\mu^2.$$
$$ P(|\bar{X^2} - (\bar{X})^2 - \sigma^2| > t) = P(|a -  b| > t) \le P(|a| > \frac{t}2) + P(|b| > \frac{t}2) = $$
$$ =  P(|\bar{X^2} -  (\sigma^2 +\mu^2)| > \frac{t}2) + P(|(\bar{X})^2-\mu^2| > \frac{t}2) \le 2exp(...) + 2exp(...)$$
So we proved that $$ P(|\bar{X^2} - (\bar{X})^2 - \sigma^2| > t) \le 2exp(...) + 2exp(...)$$
Put $y = \frac{n}{n-1}t$. So
$$P(|S^2 - \sigma^2| > y) = P(|S^2 - \sigma^2| > \frac{n}{n-1}t) =  P(|\bar{X^2} - (\bar{X})^2 - \sigma^2| > y ) \le 2exp(...) + 2exp(...)$$
